# How to stop the jquery element being added on ajax requests

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

I've added a toggle for my superfish menu, it works fine but for every ajax load or colorbox trigger the span is created multiple times. How to fix it???

```
(function ($){
Drupal.behaviors.customjs  = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#superfish-1").before("<span class='toggle'>Menu</span>");
$('#superfish-1').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way would be to use the **context of the behaviour along with .once()** as mentioned here ( https://www.drupal.org/node/1667874 ), something like below:

```
(function ($){
  Drupal.behaviors.customjs  = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Add context along with .once something like below.
      $("#superfish-1", context).once("CLASS-NAME").before("<span class='toggle'>Menu</span>");
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Damn, I had network failure and my answer got sent after yours. Anyway, +1 from me as we basically did the same thing. I'll leave mine in place, I think it is bit more descriptive.

Comment: @Mołot Yeah please keep yours as well.

Comment: Thanks ankit and @Molot choosing this as the right ans and upvoting Molot's

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `$(document).ready` in behavior. It should not be needed to make behavior work when things are ready, and second, usually it will be executed immediately if page was ready in the past - not what you want.

Second thing is to always use context in top level `$(` selectors. And use `once()` to be sure.

So your code after changes could look like this:

```
(function ($){
  Drupal.behaviors.customjs  = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $("#superfish-1", context).once("customjs-before").before("<span class='toggle'>Menu</span>");
      $("#superfish-1", context).once("customjs-toggle").toggle();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add jQuery once to your menu wrapper http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-7-prevent-duplicating-javascript-behaviors